Question about the derivative of contravariant momentum 4-vector wrt proper time
I'm confused about an expression I saw without further explanation. It is the total derivative of the contravariant momentum 4-vector wrt proper time:
$$\frac{dp^{\mu}}{d\tau}=\frac{d}{d\tau}(g^{\mu\nu}p_{\nu})=\dot{x}^{\rho}(\partial_{\rho}g^{\mu\nu})p_{\nu}$$
It's the last step I'm confused about. Do we have to express the metric in the dot products of the basevectors (products of partial derivatives)?

Saw where? Which page?

Does your dot notation. $\dot{x}$, mean the same thing as $\frac{d x}{d\tau}$?

The purpose of the third term (actually of the whole derivation) is to make the connection coefficients (Christoffel symbols) appear. For that you need to use the chain rule (*) to shift the differentiation with respect to proper time (worldline parameter) to a differentiation with respect to coordinates.
You don't need to express the metric tensor in terms of other objects, it's already there to begin with.
(*)$$\frac{d g^{\mu\nu}}{d\tau} = \frac{\partial g^{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\rho}} \frac{d x^\rho}{d\tau} = \dot{x}^\rho \partial_\rho g^{\mu\nu} $$
